# Playing videos in a browser cross device

Tags: android, ios, video, html5-video, jwplayer

I want to embed video's on our website that should work with these restrictions:

- The video needs to start as soon as the user clicks on play. As far as I can tell this means that the video must be either streamed or it must use progressive downloads.
- The video must not be downloadable by sending the link to other people.
- The video must be protected against being viewed without being allowed to do so.
- The video must work on all devices, also the ones that do not support flash such
  as iOS and android

As a backend I use amazon cloudfront. So far we have used RTMP, but that obviously does not work for iOS or android devices.

What we’re planning to do is this:

- For flash platforms we use RTMP with the amazon signed URL’s to prevent anyone to view the content.
- For iOS we want to use HLS with a generated m3u8 file that contains signed URL’s to the TS files
- For Andoid devices I'm not yet sure what to use.

My questions are these:

- Is this a viable setup, or are is there a superior setup that ticks all the boxes?
- What should we use for the android case?

Comment: I think this is a viable set up.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, use pre-signed hls/m3u8 for both ios and flash.(https://github.com/mangui/HLSprovider). For Android you can use normale html5 video streams with quality selection (signed URLs of course).

Answer (score 0):

For Android you have to use RTSP protocol. 
Wowza media server is the perfect solution for you.

Comment: Will this work on a plain HTML5 video tag in an android browser? i can't find a list of browsers that support it.